# a bash script to change postgresql user password

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, command

I can change the postgresql user password in this way (2 steps):

```
$ su - postgres -c 'psql -U postgres -d postgres'
# Alter user postgres with password 'password';
```

Now I want to use a single line command (1 step) to change the password such as:

```
su - postgres -c 'psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "alter user postgres with password ''password'';"'
```

I heard using double single quote to escape one single quote so I added double quote `'`. However is shows error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "password"
LINE 1: alter user postgres with password password;
```

Could someone let me know how to use one line of command to do this?

Comment: I actually voted this as off-topic for migration to superuser.com. It *really* irritates me that Stack Overflow puts my name in as someone who closevoted it for being "not a real question" when I voted to migrate it.

Comment: Then vote to reopen!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Easier if you use `sudo`:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "alter user postgres with password 'password';"
```

but it's possible with su too, this should work:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -U postgres -d postgres -c \"alter user postgres with password 'password';\""
```

I've used outer double quotes and escaped the inner double quotes so they pass through as part of a single call argument to `su` and get unescaped by the shell so the actual query text gets passed as  a single arg to psql including the single-quoted password.

One of the reasons sudo is easier for this is that it uses a smarter way of executing the subprocess instead of running a second shell instance to do it. You need one less layer of shell metacharacter escaping.

Comment: I used this as resource to try automate the provisioning of uuid extensions but am hitting problems I don't quite get. su command I am using is `su - postgres -c "psql -d template1 -c \"CREATE EXTENSION \"uuid-ossp\";\""` however I am getting a syntax error similar to that if you used that command in the psql shell with the `uuid-ossp` unquoted. I thought I had adequately escaped my quotes. Any ideas?

Comment: Ended creating a Here Document but would still love to know how to do this as a one liner..

Comment: @markdsievers Use `sudo`. It's much saner, as it doesn't require an extra layer of quoting. `sudo -u postgres psql -d template1 -c "..."`

Comment: If it helps anyone that has issues with this and using characters like dashes in the usernames:

`sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter user \"username-with-dash\" with password 'password-with-dash';"`

Comment: You are a life saver! :)